# WP: Get wp_post, wp_meta_value[contact] for specific term id

Tags: mysql, wordpress

I've been trying to figure out how to get the wp_meta_value depending on the term ID.

This is where I'm at so far but my head is spinning now! If you can help, I'd much appreciate it :)

Thanks

```
SELECT wp_posts.post_title
FROM wp_posts
LEFT JOIN wp_term_relationships ON (
wp_posts.ID = wp_term_relationships.object_id
)
LEFT JOIN wp_term_taxonomy ON (
wp_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id = wp_term_taxonomy.term_taxonomy_id
)
WHERE wp_posts.post_status =  'publish'
AND wp_term_taxonomy.term_id =2
ORDER BY post_title DESC 
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

Comment: I forgot to mention that the meta_key field is "contact" and I wish to retrieve the meta_value field.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work...

```
    SELECT wp_posts.post_title, wp_postmeta.meta_value AS  'Contact Details'
FROM wp_posts
LEFT JOIN wp_term_relationships ON ( wp_posts.ID = wp_term_relationships.object_id ) 
LEFT JOIN wp_term_taxonomy ON ( wp_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id = wp_term_taxonomy.term_taxonomy_id ) 
LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta ON ( wp_postmeta.post_id = wp_posts.ID ) 
WHERE wp_posts.post_status =  'publish'
AND wp_postmeta.meta_key =  'contact'
AND wp_term_taxonomy.term_id =2
ORDER BY post_title;
```